"We take these items to be …" VS "These items we take to be …" — How natural to put "these items" forward?
the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 600:

We therefore include in the preposition category all of the subordinating conjunctions of traditional grammar, with three exceptions. The exceptions are, first, "whether"; second, those occurrences of "if" that are equivalent to "whether" (as in "Ask him if he minds"); and, third, "that" when it introduces a subordinate clause. These items we take to be markers of subordination, not heads of the constructions in which they figure: see Ch. 11, §8.1, for detailed discussion of this issue.

I don't understand why "these items" was fronted in the following sentence:
(1) These items we take to be markers of subordination, not heads of the constructions in which they figure.
Fronting "these items" seems odd to me. Why is it possible here?
As far as I understand, there must be serious grounds in order that fronting a direct object be grammatical. What are these grounds here?
my variant:
(2) We take these items to be markers of subordination, not heads of the constructions in which they figure.
What's the difference between (1) and (2)?

”Bla...bla...bla...in fact this song I play every time I get into the car“ instead of "I play this song every time..” This type of inversion OSV or fronting  is not rare in English.

Related: Why does this sentence use "attack we will" instead of "we will attack"? and Does the O-S-V sentence sound normal in a formal context and The pattern with main-stressed "it is" at the end as in "I'd like a burger please. - Ok, a burger it is."

This question is similar to: Is it correct to say "In the room lay a table"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also similar to https:Boy, am I thirsty

For any referential term to work, it needs to be easy to identify the referent. In this case we need to identify which items are meant by these. The link has been made evident by proximity.
In other words, if it were "We take these items", it would be much more ambiguous whether this referred to the items just mentioned or to other items about to be mentioned. When the phrase is fronted, the second possibility is essentially eliminated (because it would be far more marked).
Another solution is to use the distal those instead of the proximal these: "We take those items to be..." In modern English, we don't use the distal to introduce new information like this,1 so it would also eliminate the ambiguity. However, it would be stylistically somewhat odd because it doesn't feel as though the items in the previous sentence are quite distant enough to justify it.

1 A common error among French speakers — French has mostly converged the proximal and distal — is to say things like "You can find more information by following that link." The link would have to have been mentioned before using the distal.

As far as I understand, there must be serious grounds in order that fronting a direct object be grammatical. What are these grounds here?

@Loviii Proximity to the referent for easier identification. For a counterexample, take the famous Decl. of Independence, where the non-fronted "these truths" refers forward rather than backward: "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal..." Fronting minimizes this possibility. But it's better to think not of needing serious grounds, but of there being degrees of markedness. We don't intuitively perceive fronted objects as wrong, just odd, with that oddness saved to various degrees by the grounds in play.

Elegantly and accessibly explained.

@Lovii   Your understanding  is correct  that a substantial reason for fronting is required in order to justify the unusualness; but you are failing to recognize the avoidance of ambiguity as a substantial reason.  Luke has explained it succinctly.  The authors are also singling out those three items, and the fronting highlights their exceptional status rhetorically.

@TimR Good point — even if we said it was only to focalize, it would be enough to explain the fronting.
